# Set the type of Node.childNodes variable in typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, casting

I have somewhere in my code:

```
const myElem: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById("asd");
let arrow: any = [];

if (myElem) {
  arrow = myElem.childNodes;
  arrow[1].style.display = "none";
  arrow[2].style.display = "block";
}
```

I'm attempting to replace the any type of the arrow variable. It needs to be declared and initialized before it gets a value.
I attempted:

```
let arrow: HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement> = [];

arrow = myElem.childNodes as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
```

Because official documentation says: `NodeList objects are collections of nodes, usually returned by properties such as Node.childNodes and methods such as document.querySelectorAll().`

and

`The read-only childNodes property of the Node interface returns a live NodeList of child nodes of the given element where the first child node is assigned index 0. Child nodes include elements, text and comments.`

[nodelist doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

[node childnode doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)

The errors I get with what I attempted:

`error TS2739: Type 'never[]' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>': item, namedItem`

`error TS2352: Conversion of type 'NodeListOf<ChildNode>' to type 'HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first. Property 'namedItem' is missing in type 'NodeListOf<ChildNode>' but required in type 'HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>'.`

Comment: Did you want `arrow = myElem.children as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;` instead?

Comment: No @Unmitigated I need to use `Node.childNodes`, but attempted to cast it to `HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>`

Comment: My parent element (`myElem` in the example) is already a `ChildNode | null type` and it doesn't have the property `element.children`, but it does have `node.childNodes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a particular reason to use `childNodes` (such as wanting non-element nodes), set the type of `arrow` to `NodeListOf<ChildNode>`. All your error messages are hinting you what to do. It's like they're saying "You said `arrow` would be a <X>, but then you assigned a value to it of type `NodeListOf<ChildNode>`, which is not like a <X>". If you go this route, you'll also have to do a type assertion / type check to use the `style` property, because that property is on the `HTMLElement` type- not on the `ChildNode` type.

Now this leaves the talk about your initialization.

If you're not going to use `arrow` again after the body of that `if` block, then just move the scope of `arrow` to go inside the `if` block. That way you don't even need to write the type annotation. TypeScript will infer it.

```
const myElem = document.getElementById("asd");
if (myElem) {
  const arrow = myElem.childNodes;
  (arrow[1] as HTMLElement).style.display = "none";
  (arrow[2] as HTMLElement).style.display = "block";
}
```

If you *will* use arrow again after the body of that `if` block, then you've better have the type reflect that it might not be initialized by the `if` block, and what you initialize it to, which would then be the value. I'd suggest you use `null` or `undefined` instead of an empty array. It's a bit more conventional. Unless you have some great reason to use an empty array as the "default" value. Whatever you do, make the typings work. Ex.

```
const myElem = document.getElementById("asd");
let arrow: NodeListOf<ChildNode> | undefined = undefined;
if (myElem) {
  arrow = myElem.childNodes;
  (arrow[1] as HTMLElement).style.display = "none";
  (arrow[2] as HTMLElement).style.display = "block";
}
```

Notice that I took out your manual typing of `myElem`. It's redundant because it's identical to the return type of `document.getElementById`.

---

If you don't have a particular reason to use `childNodes` (such as wanting non-element nodes), you could also use [`HTMLElement.children()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children), which returns a `HTMLCollection`, but you'll have to do a type assertion / type check to `HTMLElement`, since the type for elements of `HTMLCollection` is `Element` and not `HTMLElement`.